# how to add field to datasource table in lightswitch html

Tags: datasource, code-behind, lightswitch-2013

I have a datasource table in lightswitch server.

[image]

i need to add the table fields dynamically(each 1 minutes) in code behind...
how to achieve?

Comment: are you wanting to add the data to this table above? and what kind of data are you wanting to insert. If you want to insert this data every minute then Lightswitch doesn't really need to control this, SQL Agent could do this for you, and Lightswitch can then just view the data you are adding. If you give more detail I may be able to help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get information into the application, something is going to have to push the information in. I'll assume that you'll use an external application to do so, this way you'll have more control over the insertion of data.

You can do so either via the OData interface, or directly into the SQL database. I'd recommend going through the OData interface as you get the benefits of the LS business logic and security.

To do so, you'll need to write a separate program that acts as or uses an OData client. You'll also have to add a service reference to this program that targets the LS app. You can then create the required LS app type (in your case, Table), and save the changes to the LS app.

You can check out http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v3/calling-an-odata-service-from-a-net-client for a detailed example of how this is done.